# Java cannot find a file existing on the server

Tags: java, spring, file-io

In my Java Spring web app I am creating an image file. This file gets a temporary name and later on I try to rename it using:

```
public void rename(String productFilename){

   String newProductFilename = "newfile.jpg";
   File input = new File(imageDir + "/products/" + productFilename);
   File output = new File(imageDir + "/products/" + newProductFilename);
   Boolean checkRename = input.renameTo(output);
}
```

For creating the temp file, I'm using:

```
public String generate(){
    String productFilename = "filename.jpg";
    ImageIO.write(out, imageFileType, new File(imageDir + "/products/" + productFilename));
    return productFilename;
}
```

the value of `imageDir` is: /var/images

Throughout the class, the imageDir variable is set to an absolute path. The strange thing is that this all works great on Windows, but when running on Linux, I get a `FileNotFoundException`.
I'm 100% sure that the file exists. Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is 'newFilename' different from 'productFilename' ? You appear to use different vars for creation and renaming. Since this works on Windows, do you have a case issue ? I would log the filenames used in writing the temp file, and those used in renaming.

Comment: Can you also paste the exception that you get?

Comment: Please see my edit. The generate function is returning the filename which the rename function is using.

Comment: The signature for rename looks fishy. Don't you want public void rename(String productFilename, String newProductFilename);

Comment: I did not post the whole function. newProductFilename is generated inside the rename function.

Comment: Does the container user have write access?

Comment: Yes. The files are created, but unable to rename and delete.

Comment: I strongly recomend to change the code a bit. Instead of returning the file name (String) in the generate function, return the `File` object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The filenames needed to be trimmed to be recognised in Linux. This, however, worked without trimming in Windows.